# How to determine that FindText dialog is closed when user click "Cancel"

Tags: c++, winapi, dialog, window-messages

This code produces simple FindText dialog window and when user clicks top-right X window close button the WM_CLOSE message is send to the hook procedure, but when clicking "cancel" button no message is produced to indicate that window ceased to be.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

UINT_PTR CALLBACK FRHookProc(HWND hdlg, UINT uiMsg, WPARAM /*wParam*/, LPARAM /*lParam*/) {
  switch (uiMsg) {
    case WM_INITDIALOG: {
      ShowWindow(hdlg, SW_SHOW);
      break;
    }
  }
  using namespace std;
  if (uiMsg == WM_CLOSE) cout << "FindTextW window has been closed";
  return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK MyWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  return DefWindowProcW(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, LPTSTR, int /* nCmdShow*/) {
  using namespace std;

  WNDCLASSEXW wc;
  wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEXW);
  wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
  wc.lpfnWndProc = &MyWndProc;
  wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
  wc.cbWndExtra = sizeof(PVOID);
  wc.hInstance = hInstance;
  wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
  wc.hIconSm = NULL;
  wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
  wc.hbrBackground = reinterpret_cast<HBRUSH>(COLOR_BACKGROUND);
  wc.lpszMenuName = L"MainMenu";
  wc.lpszClassName = L"window";
  ATOM class_atom = RegisterClassExW(&wc);

  HWND hWnd = CreateWindowExW(
    0,
    reinterpret_cast<LPCWSTR>(class_atom),
    L"window title",
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_THICKFRAME,
    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    hInstance,
    NULL
  );

  WCHAR szFindWhat[MAX_PATH] = {0};

  FINDREPLACEW fr;
  ZeroMemory(&fr, sizeof(fr));
  fr.lStructSize = sizeof(fr);
  fr.hwndOwner = hWnd;
  fr.lpstrFindWhat = szFindWhat;
  fr.lpfnHook = FRHookProc;
  fr.wFindWhatLen = MAX_PATH;
  fr.Flags = FR_ENABLEHOOK;
  /*HWND hdlg =*/ FindTextW(&fr);

  MSG msg;
  for (;;) {
    GetMessageW(&msg, 0, 0, 0);
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessageW(&msg);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe i am wrong, but WM_DESTROY is not send?

Answer (score 2):

[Read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646956.aspx) more carefully.  You took the completely wrong approach to detecting the dialog window being closed.

[FindText function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646918.aspx):

> Before calling FindText, you **must call the RegisterWindowMessage function** to get the identifier for the FINDMSGSTRING message. The dialog box procedure uses this identifier to send messages when the user clicks the Find Next button, or **when the dialog box is closing**.

[FINDMSGSTRING message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646872.aspx):

> A Find or Replace dialog box sends the FINDMSGSTRING registered message **to the window procedure of its owner window** when the user clicks the Find Next, Replace, or Replace All button, or **closes the dialog box**.
>
> ...
>
> You must specify the FINDMSGSTRING constant in a call to the RegisterWindowMessage function to get the identifier for the message sent by the dialog box.
>
> **When you create the dialog box, use the hwndOwner member of the FINDREPLACE structure to identify the window to receive FINDMSGSTRING messages**.
>
> ...
>
> The Flags member of the FINDREPLACE structure includes one of the following flags to indicate the event that caused the message.
>
> **FR_DIALOGTERM  (0x00000040)
>   The dialog box is closing**. After the owner window processes this message, a handle to the dialog box is no longer valid.

So, with that said, try this instead:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

static const UINT uFindMsgString = RegisterWindowMessageW(L"commdlg_FindReplace");

LRESULT CALLBACK MyWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  if ((Msg == uFindMsgString) && (Msg != 0))
  {
    FINDREPLACE *fr = reinterpret_cast<FINDREPLACE*>(lParam);
    if (fr->flags & FR_DIALOGTERM)
    {
      std::cout << "FindTextW window has been closed";
      PostQuitMessage(0);
    }

    // process other dialog notifications as needed...

    return 0;
  }

  return DefWindowProcW(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, LPTSTR, int /* nCmdShow*/)
{
  WNDCLASSEXW wc = {0};
  wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEXW);
  wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
  wc.lpfnWndProc = &MyWndProc;
  wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
  wc.cbWndExtra = sizeof(PVOID);
  wc.hInstance = hInstance;
  wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
  wc.hIconSm = NULL;
  wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
  wc.hbrBackground = reinterpret_cast<HBRUSH>(COLOR_BACKGROUND);
  wc.lpszMenuName = L"MainMenu";
  wc.lpszClassName = L"window";

  ATOM class_atom = RegisterClassExW(&wc);

  HWND hWnd = CreateWindowExW(
    0,
    wc.lpszClassName,
    L"window title",
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_THICKFRAME,
    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    hInstance,
    NULL
  );

  WCHAR szFindWhat[MAX_PATH] = {0};

  FINDREPLACEW fr = {0};
  fr.lStructSize = sizeof(fr);
  fr.hwndOwner = hWnd;
  fr.lpstrFindWhat = szFindWhat;
  fr.wFindWhatLen = MAX_PATH;

  HWND hdlg = FindTextW(&fr);

  MSG msg;
  while (GetMessageW(&msg, 0, 0, 0) > 0)
  {
    if (!IsDialogMessage(hdlg, &msg))
    {
      TranslateMessage(&msg);
      DispatchMessageW(&msg);
    }
  }

  DestroyWindow(hWnd);
  UnregisterClass(wc.lpszClassName, hInstance);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be getting a [`WM_COMMAND`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647591%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) notification for the cancel button's [`BN_CLICKED`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761825%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message. When 'cancel' is pressed you should get that notification for the IDCANCEL control ID.